How to shrink the file size of a recently trimmed MySQL InnoDB table?
I have a table which used to contain 60+M rows, with a filesize of over 100GB of .ibd (innodb_file_per_table=1).
I recently removed 90% of the rows, and performed ALTER TABLE bigtable FORCE, which resulted in the "table size" as shown by phpmyadmin to shrink from 60GB to 20GB, but the .ibd didn't shrink at all. I'm pretty sure most of that file is empty, it grew by mistake, so how do I get it to shrink again? The documentation says OPTIMIZE TABLE or DEFRAGMENT or ALTER...FORCE is essentially the same for InnoDBs and performs a reimport. So why doesn't the reimport cause the file to get rebuilt with only existing data, and how do I get it to do that? Other than stopping MySQL and dumping and reimporting, that is, as I'd rather avoid a complete downtime.

Never mind, I'm an idiot. The OPTIMIZE query was failing due to lack of free disk space - somehow for optimizing a table stored in a 100 GB .ibd file required over 140 GB of space, or else it would fail. The resulting table is a mere 14 GB now, once I freed the ridiculous margin of space needed.
